# Want to understand code flow of console.log.call.call.call.call.call.apply(a => a, [1, 2]);

Tags: javascript

I know how [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) methods works, but coming to this question, it's some what tricky for me to understand the flow. Can someone help me to understand this.

```js
console.log.call.call.call.call.call.apply(a => a, [1, 2]);
```

Comment: Why? Where are you seeing this code? Job interview?

Comment: Nope, one of my friend asked me :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: @alfasin No, it's an interesting puzzle. It's not [a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for Stack Overflow. There is no context around the use of this code. The OP has not provided any information on what he/she does or doesn't understand about this code, and there is no practical use for this code in any real-world application. Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial site. We state in our guidelines that you should do your research before posting. Clearly, that wasn't done here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the fact that it wasn't asked according to the guidelines doesn't mean that it's not a good question!

Comment: What exactly are you confused by? Are you unsure what `console.log` is, or what `.call` and `.apply` are, or what `a => a` means? Please be more specific.

Comment: @alfasin If it doesn't conform to the Stack Overflow guidelines, then it's not a good question *for Stack Overflow*, hence the down votes. I can ask a great Quantum Physics question, but if I ask it to the guy at the movie theater, it's not appropriate.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I suspect that it's not each part to it's own, which is indeed pretty clear, but the combination of all of them...

Comment: @ScottMarcus what you wrote is correct. But there's also this: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: @alfasin What's your point? The first thing listed there is the same link I posted about how to ask a question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I was referring to 3 out of the four sections under "Our Expectations"

Comment: @alfasin Tell me exactly what I've said that was opposed to anything listed there? I gave details about what was wrong with the question. I did not insult anyone and wasn't mean to anyone. I haven't called anyone names. You asked why the down votes and I've very clearly answered you. Please don't confuse an answer you don't like with someone somehow mistreating you. We have a voting system and pre-determined reasons for closing questions for a reason. Using them doesn't violate the code of conduct.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm not offended in any way from you! What I'm suggesting is that a feedback in how to improve the question can be provided without downvotes, and only if the OP is non-responsive or is not willing to improve - then we should downvote/ close. I suspect that downvoting makes new-comers feel unwelcome and we're trying to work hard to improve that.

Comment: @Robofan this is a good start, but it doesn't explain how the output is 2. (Or maybe it's my bad and I didn't fully understand your explanation).

Comment: @alfasin Did I not provide a link to our guidelines on How to Ask a Good Question? You'll never be able to police down votes and frankly, there is wide latitude here on using them. The question of whether to require down votes to be accompanied by a comment has been raised dozens of times over the years and the decision has always been no.

Comment: @ScottMarcus that's a good point! Again, my comments were not referred to you personally, it's good that you provided the link (otherwise I would have :). I'm not trying to police downvotes, I don't think that it's possible (or desirable) to do so. I just wanted to raise awareness about how (I believe) we should treat newcomers (again - not directed specifically towards you).

Comment: @alfasin FYI: The OP has been a member of SO for nearly 5 years. Hardly a newcommer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I find reputation to be a better indicator than when was the first time the OP used SO. The last question he asked was ~1.5 years ago...

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's by bad not to follow the guidelines, sorry for that. It's been a while posting a question.

Comment: @KGopi in this case, all you needed to do was to add links to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and say that even after reading the docs you're not clear on why the output is 2. You can still do that (improve the question). Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, note that in JavaScript, functions are objects, and can have their own properties (which you can access with the `.` notation just like any other object). Of the properties that exist on all functions are [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), which are themselves functions.

Second, both `.call` and `.apply` provide a mechanism to invoke a function with a specified [*`this`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) value. To understand that, `this` normally refers to whatever is on the left-hand side of the `.` when you call a function as a method of an object, e.g. when you call `foo.bar(1, 2, 3)`, within the context of `bar`, `this` will refer to `foo`.  So it's also possible to use `bar.call(foo, 1, 2, 3)` or `bar.apply(foo, [1, 2, 3])` to achieve a similar effect; in both cases the first argument becomes `this`.

So basically, the `console.log` and all the `.call`'s  except the last one don't actually matter. The initial part of the code is just trying to apply `.call` on *some* function, and could just as easily be replaced with `Function.prototype.call.apply`

Skipping ahead a bit, `a => a` is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), short-hand for `function(a) { return a; }`. It creates an anonymous function that accepts one argument and returns that same argument as result. Note that this function doesn't actually refer to `this` so all the previous calls to `.call` and `.apply` are pretty much irrelevant.

Last `[1, 2]` is just an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) literal containing two items, `1` and `2` which be unrolled as arguments by `.apply`.

So breaking it down:

```
console.log.call.call.call.call.call.apply(a => a, [1, 2]);
```

Can be reduced to:

```
Function.prototype.call.apply(a => a, [1, 2]);
```

Can be reduced to:

```
var fn = a => a;
fn.call(1, 2);
```

`.call` will use its first argument as the `this` value of the function and pass subsequent values as parameters, and since `fn` doesn't use `this`, we can further reduce it to:

```
var fn = a => a;
fn(2);
```

Since `fn` is just a simple identity function, the result is just:

```
2;
```

Comment: Way better than my now-deleted answer. Nicely explained.

Comment: I honesty didn't understand the behavior until I read your answer - thanks mucho!

Comment: Awesome man, actually i know how call and apply method works, but i got mislead/confused with the statement/code pattern !!

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't do anything, apply will return `1` and `2` as separate values which `call` won't do anything with since it's not a function. Even if you were to do `console.log.call.call(a => a, [1,2])` you wouldn't get anything since the first call returns just the array `[1,2]` which isn't a function the second `call` can do anything with...

```js
console.log.call.call./*and so on*/call./*returns nothing eval({1, 2}) = 
undefined*/call./*returns {1, 2} up the chain*/apply(a => a, [1,2]);

//You can try this which also won't return anything:
console.log.call([1,2]);
```

Although oddly enough I was expecting this sort of code to throw an error, which it didn't, it just didn't log or throw an error. So it really doesn't return anything...